# Deploy a Vue.js App with Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

What is the best Way to deploy a vue.js app initialy created with vue-cli to Firebase Hosting?
I prepared the vue-app for deployment with

`npm run build`

This creates the folder "dist" with the bundled js-file and assets like pictures.

Then- after installing firebase tools globaly, I run

```
firebase init
```

This creates a folder "public" with a default index.html file inside.

First i set in firebase.json:

```
  "hosting": {
"public": "dist"
```

}

and copied the index.html (the vue index.hltm) from the root-folder to "dist" folder.
Then i deployed with

```
firebase deploy
```

It runs, but the paths to the pictures seem to be broken .
I set public folder to "public" in firebase.json

```
      "hosting": {
"public": "public"
```

}

an put vue index.html there, but then "dist" is not found.
I moved the "dist"-folder inside the "public"folder, and finaly- App is online on firebase.

But now `npm run dev` is not working any more. Firebase cli seems to break vue-cli.

So how to get  vue-cli and firebase-cli playing together?

Answer (score 1):

When you run `firebase init` few questions will be asked, like which firebase feature you want to use and select your project... when cli asks for

```
? What do you want to use as your public directory?
```

Type `dist` your desired folder. Now the dist folder will be deployed.

Check this [link](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/deploy-your-app-to-firebase-in-seconds-b3a9a37dff47), Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured it out. 
First, keep two separatet Projects, one for vue app and one for Firebase-Hosting.
So the CLI's can work independently and nothing gets broken. Develop your vue.js App and prepare for deploy with `npm run build`. All you need afterwards is the `index.html` in vue-project root and the folder `dist`
Create Firebase project with CLI executing `firebase init` in empty Folder. Here you can also maintain firebase functions if needed.

You define public directory during `firebase init` or afterwards editing entry in firebase.json

`"hosting": { "public": "public"}`

This will become the root-directory of your App. Vue.js expects to have `index.html` directly in the root-directory and a subfolder `dist` inside it.
So defining `dist` as root-directory is not what you want. Related paths like those for pictures in vue-app get broken.
Leave settings for public at default. Then copy `index.html` and `dist`-folder from vue-project inside `public` directory in Firebase-project.
If you want, you can now test localy what will get deployed using `firebase serve`
If everything fine, deploy using `firebase deploy`

Answer (score 0):

`dist` should be your public folder. Here is the working configuration for VueJS with Firebase hosting:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've also written a written an in-depth guide on [auto-deploying VueJS apps to Firebase hosting](https://coffeencoding.com/auto-deploy-vuejs-app-to-firebase-hosting-with-gitlab-cd/)